# Python - 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, string, list

I've searched this error on here, but haven't seen anything that yet matches my situation (disclaimer, I'm still getting used to `Python`).

```
    import os
    os.chdir("C:\Projects\Rio_Grande\SFR_Checking")  # set working directory

    stressPeriod = 1
    segCounter = 1
    inFlow = 0
    outFlow = 0

    with open(r"C:\Projects\streamflow.dat") as inputFile:
        inputList = list(inputFile)

    while stressPeriod <= 1:
        segCounter = 1
        lineCounter = 1
        outputFile = open("stats.txt", 'w') # Create the output file
        for lineItem in inputList:
            if (((stressPeriod - 1) * 11328) + 8) < lineCounter <= (stressPeriod * 11328):
                lineItem = lineItem.split()
                if int(lineItem[3]) == int(segCounter) and int(lineItem[4]) == int(1):
                    inFlow = lineItem[5]
                    outFlow = lineItem[7]
                    lineItemMem = lineItem
                elif int(lineItem[3]) == int(segCounter) and int(lineItem[4]) <> int(1):
                    outFlow = lineItem[7]
                else:
                    gainLoss = str(float(outFlow) - float(inFlow))
                    lineItemMem.append(gainLoss)
                    lineItemMem = ','.join(lineItemMem)
                    outputFile.write(lineItemMem + "\n")  # write # lines to file
                    segCounter += 1
                    inFlow = lineItem[5]
                    outFlow = lineItem[7]
            lineCounter += 1
outputFile.close()
```

So basically this program is supposed to read a .dat file and parse out `bits` of information from it. I split each line of the file into a list to do some `math` on it (math operations are between varying lines in the file, which adds complexity to the code). I then append a new number to the end of the list for a given line, and that's where things inexplicably break down. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chuck/Desktop/Python/SFR/SFRParser2.py", line 49, in <module>
    lineItemMem.append(gainLoss)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

When I give it a print command to test that `lineItemMem` is actually a list and not a string, it prints a list for me. If I put in code for

`lineItemMem.split(",")` to break the string, I get an error saying that `list` object has no attribute `split`. So basically, when I try to do `list` operations, the error says its a `string`, and when I try to do string operations, the error says it's a list. I've tried a fair bit of mucking around, but frankly can't tell what the problem is here. Any insight is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: What is `type(lineItemMem)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places where `lineItemMem` is set. The first is this:

```
lineItem = lineItem.split()
# ...
    lineItemMem = lineItem
```

where it is set to the result of a split operation, i.e. a List.

The second place is this:

```
lineItemMem = ','.join(lineItemMem)
```

here, it is set to the result of a join operation, i.e. a String.

So, the reason why the error sometimes states that it is a string and sometimes a list is, that that is *acutally the case* depending on the conditions in the if statement.

The code, as presented, is imho near undebuggable. Instead of tinkering, it would be a better approach to think about the different goals that should be achieved (reading a file, parsing the content, formatting the data, writing it to another file) and tackle them individually.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue has to do with these lines:

```
                lineItemMem.append(gainLoss)
                lineItemMem = ','.join(lineItemMem)
```

Initially `lineItemMem` is a list, and you can append an item to the end of it. However, the `join` call you're doing turns the list into a string. That means the next time this part of the code runs, the `append` call will fail.

I'm not certain exactly what the best solution is. Perhaps you should use a different variable for the string version? Or maybe after you join the list items together into a single string and write that result out, you should reinitialize the `lineItemMem` variable to a new empty list? You'll have to decide what works best for your actual goals.